# Merge multiple <br /> tags to a single one with python lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I've a python script to clean scraped html content, it uses BeautifulSoup4 and works pretty well. Recently I have decided to learn lxml but I found the tutorials are harder (for me) to follow. For example I use the following code to merge multiple `<br />` tags into one, i.e, if there are more than one `<br />` tags, remove all but keep just one:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
data = 'foo<br /><br>bar. <p>foo<br/><br id="1"><br/>bar'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for br in soup.find_all("br"):
    while isinstance(br.next_sibling, Tag) and br.next_sibling.name == 'br':
        br.next_sibling.extract()
print soup
<html><body><p>foo<br/>bar. </p><p>foo<br/>bar</p></body></html>
```

How do I achieve this similar in lxml? Thanks,

Comment: if `lxml` is installed then it is used *silently* (it might be harmful) as a parser by `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: this confuses me: i've heard that lxml is faster than bs4, by your saying, i won't lose speed even if i use bs4 as long as i have lxml installed?

Comment: the only benchmark that matters is your code. Measure it: run in a virtualenv where lxml is not installed (`import lxml` must fail) and then run in a virtualenv where lxml is installed (you could also specify the parser explicitly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `.drop_tag()` method to remove duplicate consecutive occurences of `<br/>` tag:

```
from lxml import html

doc = html.fromstring(data)
for br in doc.findall('.//br'):
    if br.tail is None: # no text immediately after <br> tag
        for dup in br.itersiblings():
            if dup.tag != 'br': # don't merge if there is another tag inbetween
                break
            dup.drop_tag()
            if dup.tail is not None: # don't merge if there is a text inbetween
               break

print(html.tostring(doc))
# -> <div><p>foo<br>bar. </p><p>foo<br>bar</p></div>
```