# scrapy / lxml.html : Consolidate multiple consecutive <br> tags

Tags: python, html, scrapy, lxml

I'm using Scrapy to gather data from a number of websites. I'm using 
w3lib.html.remove_tags with Compose in my ScrapyField() declarations to entirely clean the HTML down to nothing but basic formatting tags: b, em, strong, i, and br. I then have a pipeline to rebuild it into cleaner, more uniform HTML for display on a another website.

A lot of the scraped HTML ends up having multiple consecutive br tags which I need to get merged down to a single br tag per occurrence. The accepted answer to this question: [Merge multiple <br /> tags to a single one with python lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779061/merge-multiple-br-tags-to-a-single-one-with-python-lxml) accomplishes exactly this, but, only when the 
 tags are not separated by whitespace. Suppose one of my ItemLoaders returns the following string:

```
<div class="info"> <br>  <br> <p class="tight"><br> Some text</p><br>  <br></div>
```

The solution referenced above does not work on them. How is it possible to consolidate these? I'm looking for a non-RegEx solution. It seems that lxml should be able to handle this, but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: I dont think of any non-regex solution, why you dont want to use Regex?

Comment: Interested to know the reason for the downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code works fine for me

```
from lxml import html
data = """
<div class="info"> <br>   <br> <br> <p class="tight"><br> Some text</p><br>  <br></div>
"""
doc = html.fromstring(data)
for br in doc.findall('.//br'):
    if br.tail is None or br.tail.strip() =='': # no text immediately after <br> tag
        for dup in br.itersiblings():
            if dup.tag != 'br': # don't merge if there is another tag inbetween
                break
            dup.drop_tag()
            if not (dup.tail is None or dup.tail.strip() == ''): # don't merge if there is a text inbetween
                break

print(html.tostring(doc))
```

Outputs:

```
b'<div class="info"> <br>     <p class="tight"><br> Some text</p><br>  </div>\n'
```

Comment: Perfect answer. So simple, I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thank you!